# how can i know which transports are currently active with winston.js

Tags: node.js, winston

Hey i am working with winston.js for logging my node.js application.

my problem is that i have several modules which each needs to remove the console transport and add a log transport.

this is my code:

```
winston.remove(winston.transports.Console);
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'somefile.log' });
```

this code is in several different modules.

the problem is that if i try to remove the same transport, say the console, more than once in different modules which are required from each other, i get and error which i can only handle with a try and catch (actually not handle).

this approach is bad since it seems not good to wrap this code with try and catch only to avoid this error.

the problem is that i didn't find any way to get the current active transports.

is there any way i can avoid using the try and catch and instead get a list of the current active transports?